# Absolute value proof 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

> I've been asked to prove the following:
>   $$\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|} \le \frac{|a|}{1+|a|} + \frac{|b|}{1+|b|}$$

Does anyone got a tip for me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}\geq\frac{|a|}{1+|a|+|b|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|a|+|b|}=$$
$$=\frac{|a|+|b|}{1+|a|+|b|}=1-\frac{1}{1+|a|+|b|}\geq1-\frac{1}{1+|a+b|}=\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The function

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}\, \qquad   (x>0)$$

is monotonically increasing because

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}>0.$$

Hence by virtue of the following

$$|a+b|<|a|+|b|$$

One can say...what?